# Does chef 'notifies :action, 'resource', :before' work at all as it should?

Tags: notifications, chef-infra

I've recently tried to perform a simple task: Install a package if it does not exist by pulling distribution out of web location (in-house repo) and deleting it once it is not longer needed.

Learning about :before notification I came up with following elegant code (in this example variable "pkg" keeps name of distribution image, "pkg_src_location" is URL of my web repository, "name_of_package" is named installed package):

```
local_image = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/#{pkg}"

remote_file 'package_image' do
  path local_image
  source "#{pkg_src_location}/#{pkg}"
  action :nothing
end

package name_of_package do
  source local_image
  notifies :create, 'remote_file[package_image]', :before
  notifies :delete, 'remote_file[package_image]', :delayed
end
```

I was quite surprised that it does not work... Actually 'package' resource is being converged without 'remote_file' being created - and it fails due to source local_image not being in place...

I did a simple test:

```
log 'before' do
  action :nothing
end

log 'after' do
  action :nothing
end

log 'at-the-end' do
  action :nothing
end

log 'main' do
  notifies :write, 'log[before]', :before
  notifies :write, 'log[at-the-end]', :delayed
  notifies :write, 'log[after]', :immediately
end
```

What I learned is that 'main' is actually converged twice! Once when first encountered and once again, after 'before' resource is converged...

```
   Recipe: notify_test::default
     * log[before] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
     * log[after] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
     * log[at-the-end] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
     * log[main] action write

     * log[before] action write

     * log[main] action write

     * log[after] action write

     * log[at-the-end] action write
```

Is it a bug or feature? If this is 'feature', it is a really bad one and Chef shouldn't have it at all. It is simply useless the way it works and only wastes people's time...

Can anyone having more in-depth Chef understanding comment on it? Is there any way to make ':before' work? Maybe I'm just doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have never heard of `:before` "notifications". I would let the `remote_file` trigger the `package` resource (which assumes that the artifact is kept on local disk).

Comment: @StephenKing the :before has been added recently, see: https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc058-before.md

Comment: @r2oro some resources doesn't support why run or are updated on every run, the log resource is one of them, hence the strange behavior you're experiencing when testing with it. Try with templates and you should have a more consistent behavior.

Comment: Could you run your package install with -l debug ?

Answer (score 3):

To be a bit more specific, the `before` timing uses the "why run" system to make a guess about if the resource needs to be updated. In this case, the package resource is invalid to begin with so whyrun can't tell that an update is needed.

Comment: Yes, I realize it now. However it's a pity that the check done by yum_package to verify if package has to be updated does not test if the package is there at all at the first place ditching idea of version comparison for package which is not there...

Yet another strange (and annoying) behaviour of yum_package is some huge repository query (full metadata cache refresh?) it does even if local rpm is specified. It leads to failures on OEL. But maybe it's OEL only issue...

Comment: Because of how whyrun works, it has to make a lot of assumptions about what kinds of failures are "okay". It's a structural weakness of how we do it.

Answer (score 2):

After a little rethink about it I get what's going wrong here:

The before notification is fired if the actual resource will have to be updated, in chef inner this mean getting the actual resource state to compare to the desired resource state ('\load_current_resource\ in providers).

Here you're willing to install a package, chef will ask the system about this package and it's version, and then will compare this result with the source you provided.

And here comes the problem, you can't compare with the source package as it is not installed.

---

For your case, the best bet is to leave the file on the system and get rid of notifications.

The before notification could be of interest if you want to launch a database backup before upgrading the DB system for example or as mentioned in the [RFC for :before](https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/blob/master/rfc058-before.md) to stop a service before upgrading its package.

But it should not be used to trigger another resource providing one of the "calling" resource properties.

Comment: I have yet another workaround for this problem - having a guard `not_if { File.exist?(path_to_file_from_pkg) }` for `remote_file` resource which then notifies `package` (that otherwise would take `action :nothing'` and with `file` `action :delete` at the end to cleanup downloaded image. I just don't like clobbering file system with leftovers after installation.
I just thought that triggering download _on demand_ as result of lack of package with given name would be more elegant...
Thanks for your suggestion regarding the check. I have just confirmed that this is the case.